# How to add old data and events in a table on an existing webpage using greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I made a greasemonkey script that tracks the user infos and populates them on the database with timestamps. So whenever I check on the webpage with below infos, the script fetches it and updates it on the database with the current timestamp. For instance:

```
Name : XYZ
Id : 123123
Age : 24
Salary : 25000
Current Whereabouts : Florida
Current Work : XXX
Allowance Generated today: 150
```

So I want to make a table below this info page showing the last 30 days activity. 
Something like this below those existing infos in the webpage:

[image: Something like this]

Comment: The goal is clear, the problem - why you can't do it - is not. Show your best attempt at implementing this if you have one.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the query to fetch latest infos for each day from the database.

Comment: I'm not an expert on SQL but I doubt anyone could telepathically guess the correct parameters without seeing that page or excerpts of its html and/or database-related code.

Comment: I figured it out myself :p `$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, username, age, whereabouts, currentwork, salary, allwgen, updatedTime FROM history WHERE username = '".$username."' AND (updatedTime <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ORDER BY updatedTime DESC LIMIT 35");
   $stmt->execute();
   $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); ` and used foreach loop to display the table.